# Javascript Objects returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object

Hello guys i'm trying objects in javascript/node.js, actually i'm having a hard time on objects with functions inside them. This is my sample code whish the output should be:

**Rohan says: Hello World**

Here is my func.js

```
var myObject = function(name) {
    console.log(this.name + ' says: ');
    this.talk = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        }
};

var phil = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};

phil.prototype = new myObject();
var man = new phil('Rohan');
man.talk('Hello World');
```

I hope you can help me solve this problem in my code. Thanks guys.

Comment: Your `myobject` function has an unused `name` parameter, and uses a (not initialized) `name` property. What do you want? Which of the two "classes" should be responsible for the name? In my answer it works, but is still confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myObject = function(name) {
    this.talk = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
        console.log(name + ' says: ');
    }
};

var phil = function (name) {
    this.setName(name);
};

phil.prototype = new myObject();
var man = new phil('Rohan');
man.talk('Hello World');
```

Comment: This is what i'm saying. This Code. :) Thanks Popsyjunior.

Comment: Try to call `man.talk('Hello world')` once again

Comment: [Do not use `phil.prototype = new myObject();`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)

Comment: You're welcome. I'll like to believe that it's a homework or something you're trying out. @Bergi is right In real life applications, you'll want to use standard javascript inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

See [Correct javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance). [Don't use the `new` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) for creating the prototype (you don't want to initialize it like an instance). Initialise the instance by applying the parent constructor. And for naming conventions: uppercase constructors would be nice.

```
function MyObject() {
    console.log(this.name + ' got created');
}
MyObject.prototype.talk = function(msg) {
    console.log("and says "+msg);
};

function Phil(name) {
    this.name = name;
    MyObject.call(this);
}
Phil.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);

var man = new Phil('Rohan');
man.talk('Hello World');
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `talk` function to

```
this.talk = function (msg) {
    console.log(this.name + ' says: ' + msg);
}
```

Comment: How is that going to solve the problem ?

Comment: This is not about how to print the name but instead it's about prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Just want to help him get the intended output. More thoroughly explain already wrote by Bergi.