# Node Inheritance with require / prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got an abstract object defined like so...

```
var abs = module.exports = function abs(val){

   if(!(this instanceof abs)){

      return new abs(val);

   }

   abs.prototype.getName = function getName(){

      return val.name;

   }

}
```

and a concrete class that I want to inherit from it defined like so...

```
 var concrete = module.exports = function concrete(val){

    var abs = require('./abs');

    if(!(this instanceof concrete)){

       return new concrete(val);

    }

    concrete.prototype = Object.create(abs.prototype);

 }
```

and when I write...

```
 var anObject { name : "John" };
 var concreteObject = new concrete(anObject);
 concrete.getName();
```

I get the following error..

```
TypeError: Object #<conrete> has no method 'getName'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you should be assigning stuff to the prototype inside a constructor.

Comment: @Musa if I don't then `val` becomes undefined in the prototype functions.

Comment: @Skizit: That's the point of prototypes - they are shared amongst all instances and cannot access their scopes.

Comment: @Bergi I see. What would be the correct way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors (left alone the missing `=`) in what your wrote:

- `concrete.getName()` does not work because `concrete` is your constructor function. It has no such method.
- `concreteObject.getName()` does not work because its prototype has no such method. You did overwrite `concrete.prototype` *in the constructor*, but then the instance was already built with the old one. Check [how the `new` operator works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

---

Therefore you need to fix those class definitions as well. As we've seen, one cannot access constructor arguments from the shared prototype functions - it would not make any sense. And assigning the prototype methods in the constructor would make the `val` of the latest `abs` invocation available to all instances. Ugh.

Use the prototype:

```
function abs(val) {
    if (!(this instanceof abs))
        return new abs(val);

    this.val = val;
}
abs.prototype.getName = function getName(){
    return this.val.name;
};
module.exports = abs;
```

or use a privileged instance method (see [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object) for explanations):

```
function abs(val){
    if (!(this instanceof abs))
        return new abs(val);

    this.getName = function getName(){
       return val.name;
    };
}
module.exports = abs;
```

---

As for that `concrete` thing, I don't understand why you need it at all - it doesn't seem to do much more than `concrete = abs;` would do. However, the [blueprint for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance) would look like this:

```
var abs = require('./abs');
function concrete(val){
    if (!(this instanceof concrete))
        return new concrete(val);

    abs.call(this, val);
}
concrete.prototype = Object.create(abs.prototype);
```