# Javascript Object Inheritance how to get the Child instance name

Tags: javascript, oop

```
/**
 * adds an entry to the list
 * 
 * @param data {Object}
 * @return this
 */
ElementList.prototype.addEntry = function(data){
    if (!data) return this;

    data['type'] = this.children_type;

    // add the entry to the current elements
    this.element_list.push(new FavoriteEntry(data));

    this.refresh();

    return this;
};

/**
 * favorites extend ElementList
 *
 * @param setting_list
 * @constructor
 */
function FavoriteList(setting_list){
    ElementList.call(this, setting_list);
}

FavoriteList.prototype = new ElementList();
FavoriteList.constructor = FavoriteList;
```

So this a short code snipplet of an educational project of mine.
What I want to do is reduce repeating code so I created a generic ElementList object 
So

- the Example FavoriteList inherties the parent Objects prototype
- The constructors is pointing to the Childobject
- the Parent constructor is called within the child.

That works just perfectly fine my problem is

```
 // add the entry to the current elements
this.element_list.push(new FavoriteEntry(data));
```

This should create a new instance of an Object BASED on the CHILD so therefore I need to get the name of the child instance that's calling the parent method

i tried 
 - this.constructor (point to the parent) 
 - this.constructor.name
 - this instanceof FavoriteList (works)

since I DON'T want to pass a name and i think iterating through instanceof "options" is not really smart.

I would ask for some insights how I can access the childs instance name in the parent elements method body.

Please I only need an explicit answer to this!! I already read workarounds! If It's not possible just say so :)

thx in advance :)

Comment: thought so :/ thx, so an ugly solution it is

Comment: I'm confused: So you do something like this: `var favList = new FavoriteList("xyz"); favList.addEntry("some data");` and you want to access `favList` inside of `addEntry`?

Comment: well the data is an object not a string -> it creates element in predefined html container. but since the events should be handled different base on the parent container i need to create dynamic instances of the "entries"

the FavList should contain FavEntries so I want to generate the "FavEntries" call 

-> "var call = FavList.constructor.replace(/List/, '')" + "Entry"();

something like that.

Comment: var call = this.constructor.name.replace('List','')  + "Entry"; window[call](data); that's what i wanted to do to be excact :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> this.element_list.push(new FavoriteEntry(data));
> ```
>
> This should create a new instance of an Object BASED on the CHILD so
>   therefore I need to get the name of the child instance that's calling
>   the parent method

No, you don't seem to need to know the name. All you need is a helper function to generate new `Entry` instances, that can be overwritten to generate more specific entries. Maybe you're already doing that by passing a `children_type` with the `data`…

> i tried - this.constructor (point to the parent)

It should work if you had set the `constructor` correctly. Change your code to

```
FavoriteList.prototype.constructor = FavoriteList;
//          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, you might want to [use `Object.create`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572) [instead of `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) to set up the prototype chain.

Comment: ahh okay that made sense :) works like a charm now.

i already change it to the ecma standard Object.create I just didn't want to repost the code :) 

thx for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand but the code `new FaforiteEntry` should create either a FororiteEntry or another type based on the current object type.

Maybe the following example could help you out:

```
var ElementList = function(args) {
  this.element_list = [];
}
ElementList.prototype.addEntry = function(args) {
  this.element_list.push(new this.entryType(args.val));
};
//will create element_list items of type String
ElementList.prototype.entryType = String;

function FavoriteList(args) {
  ElementList.call(this, args);
}
FavoriteList.prototype = Object.create(ElementList.prototype);
FavoriteList.constructor = FavoriteList;
//will create element_list items of type Array
FavoriteList.prototype.entryType = Array;

//adding entries to f would create items of type Array
var f = new FavoriteList();
f.addEntry({val: 2});
console.log(f.element_list);//[[undefined, undefined]]
//adding entries to e would create items of type String
var e = new ElementList();
e.addEntry({val: 2});
console.log(e.element_list);//[ String { 0="2"...
```

Comment: thx but Bergi gave me the answer I needed. i had to assign the obj.prototype.constructor so I could access the name of the child object that called the generic object. :) 

`var call = this.constructor.name.replace('List','')  + "Entry";
    // add the entry to the current elements
    this.element_list[data.id] = new window[call](data);`

that's what I wanted to do :)

Comment: @shadowdroid I see, please note that the variable FavoriteList is assigned to a nameless function in my code and this.name would not return what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code example:

```
 function Parent(){
        // custom properties
    }

    Parent.prototype.getInstanceName = function(){
        for (var instance in window){
            if (window[instance] === this){
                return instance;
            }
        }
    };

    var child = new Parent();

    console.log(child.getInstanceName()); // outputs: "child"
```

Comment: @shadowdroid  Note: This implementation works if the instance was created in the root.