# How to set javascript prototype correct

Tags: javascript, prototype

I got the following code snippet and was wondering why the prototype is not set. It looks like the getCompany method is overriding the getName method. Is this because the return clause return a JSON and overrides all other methods? It should only override the prototype function if the method names are equal. I need to write in the "return form" to expose only certain methods.

```
Person = function(name) {

  var name = name;

  return {
    getName: function() {return this.name;}

  }; 
};

SecondPerson = function(name) {
    this.name = name;

   return {
        getCompany: function(){alert("lolz");}
 };
}
SecondPerson.prototype= new Person();
SecondPerson.prototype.constructor = SecondPerson;



var tom = new SecondPerson("Tom");
alert(tom.getName());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this because the return clause return a JSON and overrides all other methods?

A "JS object literal", but yes.

> I need to write in the "return form" to expose only certain methods.

No you don't. To only expose certain properties, do only put certain methods on the instance (`this` inside the constructor):

```
function Person(name) {
    this.getName = function() {return name;};
}
```

Also you seem to have confused variables with properties - see [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572).

Now if we have that settled, it comes to [Correct javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572). You [should not use `new` for creating the prototype object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572). For creating instance-specific properties, you will have to explicitly apply the parent constructor on the new instance.

```
function SecondPerson(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
    this.getCompany = function(){alert("lolz");}; // might be defined on the prototype
}
SecondPerson.prototype= Object.create(Person.prototype);
SecondPerson.prototype.constructor = SecondPerson;
```