# Override constructor in the Object.create inheritance pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'd like a subclass' constructor to call it's parent's constructor before executing itself, with the `Object.create` pattern.

#### Using `new Parent()`

```
var Parent = function(){ console.log( 'Parent' ) };
var Child  = function(){ console.log( 'Child' ) };
Child.prototype = new Parent(); // Prints 'Parent'
var child = new Child(); // Prints 'Child'
```

#### Using `Object.create`

```
var Parent = function(){ console.log( 'Parent' ) };
var Child  = function(){ console.log( 'Child' ) };
Child.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );
var child = new Child(); // I'd like this to print 'Parent' then 'Child'
```

Is this even possible? Can I add something like `Parent.call( this )` in the `Child` constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct javascript inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add something like `Parent.call( this )` in the Child constructor?

Yes, just do exactly this.

```
var Parent = function(){ console.log( 'Parent' ) };
var Child  = function(){ Parent.call(this); console.log( 'Child' ) };
Child.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype ); // should print nothing
var child = new Child(); // prints 'Parent' then 'Child'
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question. You already answered it, though.

```
var Parent = function(){console.log('Parent')};
var Child = function(){
  console.log('Child')
  Parent.call(this);
};
Child.prototype = new Parent();
var child = new Child();
```

in the Firebug console produces

```
Parent
Child
Parent
Object { }
```

as output.