# Javascript inheritance - Ctor parameters and overriding functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to teach myself javascript inheritance.
I have created the following code and try to make it work (After reading some related posts around here). 
I must use cross browser syntax and want to use only pure js. 
How can I fix the following code?

Update: (After Bergi remarks, Now fully working...)

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Tests</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Animal(name)
    {
        alert("animal ctor " + name);
        this.animalName = name;
    };

    //Base implementation
    Animal.prototype.move = function()
    {
        alert("I am walking");
    };

    //Base implementation
    Animal.prototype.makeVoice = function ()
    {
        alert("Not implemented");
    };

    Animal.prototype.introduce = function ()
    {
        alert("This is " + this.animalName);
    };

    function Bird(name)
    {
        alert("bird ctor " + name);
        Animal.call(this, name);

        //Derived only
        this.standOnWire = function ()
        {
            alert("I'm standing on an electricity wire");
        };
    };

    Bird.prototype = new Animal();
    Bird.prototype.constructor = Bird;

    //Override
    Bird.prototype.move = function()
    {
        alert("I am flying");
    };

            //Override
    Bird.prototype.makeVoice= function ()
    {
        alert("twit twit");
    };

    function Cow(name)
    {
        alert("cow ctor " + name);
        Animal.call(this, name);

        //Derived only
        this.produceMilk = function ()
        {
            alert("I am producing milk");
        };
    };

    Cow.prototype = new Animal();
    Cow.prototype.constructor = Cow;

    //Override
    Cow.prototype.makeVoice = function ()
    {
        alert("mmmooooooo");
    };

    function runCowTests()
    {
        alert('runCowTests');

        var cow1 = new Cow('Cow');

        cow1.introduce();
        cow1.move();
        cow1.makeVoice();
        cow1.produceMilk();
    };

    function runBirdTests()
    {
        alert('runBirdTests');

        var bird1 = new Bird('Canary');

        bird1.introduce();
        bird1.move();
        bird1.makeVoice();
        bird1.standOnWire();
    };
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <input type="button" value="bird tests" onclick="runBirdTests();" />
     <input type="button" value="cow tests" onclick="runCowTests();" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The following answer may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I fix the following code?

A few things:

- move the [assignments to the prototype outside the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255957/assigning-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor-function-why-not)!
- `myName` is superfluous, just use the already existing variable `name` as it is
- `self` is superfluous, just use `this`
- the `.call()` method is spelled lowercase
- use `….prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)` - see [Correct javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572)
- you're assigning `undefined`, the result of the IEFEs, to `runCowTests` and `runBirdTests` - not sure whether that is on purpose

```
function Bird(name) { 
    Animal.call(self, name);
}
// put this first
Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
// Don't:
// Bird.prototype = {…} - overwrites above assignment

// Derived only
Bird.prototype.standOnWire = function () {
    alert("I'm standing on an electricity wire");
};
// Override
Bird.prototype.move = function () {
    alert("I am flying");
};
// Override
Bird.prototype.makeVoice = function () {
    alert("twit twit");
};
```

Comment: @Yaron: `Object.create` is from 2009! And supported since IE9, btw. If you need to support any outdated engines, you still can include the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) and use it without problems.

Comment: Bergi can you please take a look at the fixed code and give me a hint about what is still wrong with it? Thank you so much!

Comment: You still haven't fixed #5, also you cannot use an object literal as it would overwrite that, and you need to put the property assignments to the prototype after the `Object.create`

Comment: My real project must support IE8 so I can't use Object.create.  What do you mean by object literal? What are property assignments to prototype? Can you give me please example?

Comment: As I said above, you can use the very simple polyfill.