# JS "inheritance" (code sharing) mechanism

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I've recently been moving out of my comfort zone with JS, and come across a situation where it  would make sense to share common functionality. What I've come up with is the following (concept only) code:

```
function subclass(parent, child) {
  child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype)
}

function URL(str) {
    this.value = str;
}

function HttpURL(str) {
    this.value = str
}

subclass(URL, HttpURL)

URL.path = function() { 
    return this.value; 
}
// ...

HttpURL.isSecure = function() { 
    this.value.substring(0, 8) === 'https://'; 
}
```

This code works as I expect it to work (making the "methods" on URL available on HttpURL, but not vice versa), but I wonder if it is "ethical" or if there is a better way of allowing this.

Comment: And what's the question? Is it ethical for two objects to share the same code? )

Comment: This is precisely how one would comfortably manage inheritance schemes  in Javascript.  Kudos!  If you're working in older environments that don't support `Object.create`, you'll have a bit more work to do, but this is the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a situation where it would make sense to share common functionality.
>
> ```
> subclass(URL, HttpURL)
> ```

Yes, that works and is the [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572) solution.

> ```
> URL.path = function() { 
>     return this.value; 
> }
> HttpURL.isSecure = function() { 
>     this.value.substring(0, 8) === 'https://'; 
> }
> ```
>
> This code works as I expect it to work (making the "methods" on URL
>   available on HttpURL, but not vice versa)

No. You want to make URL methods available on HttpUrl *instances*, for which you would need to use the prototype:

```
URL.prototype.path = function() { 
    return this.value; 
}
HttpURL.prototype.isSecure = function() { 
    this.value.substring(0, 8) === 'https://'; 
}
```

Otherwise they won't be inherited.