# Define a prototype using new operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was exploring prototype in JavaScript.

```
function A () { this.x = 7; };
function B () {};
B.prototype = new A();
var b = new B();
b.x; // => 7
// But why is it giving 'false' below
b.hasOwnProperty('x'); // => false
```

My Query is,
is it correct code?
If 'b' is has a value for 'x' , then it should be its property. If so, why is it giving false.
Please clarify.

Comment: Because it's an inherited, not an own property. That's what prototypes are all about.

Comment: No, you're not doing [correct javascript inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572). See also [what's wrong about the use of `new` here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

`b.x` is a property on the **prototype** of `b`, not on `b` itself.
`hasOwnProperty` only checks for own properties, hence the name.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, you mean:  b.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('x'); // => true

Answer (score 1):

x is a property on `B.prototype` and not on object b. B.prototype gets stored on b.**proto** and not on `b` itself.

Regarding your code, you should additionally do this:

```
function B(){ A.apply(this, arguments); }
```

This would make sure the base constructor is invoked whenever B() constructor is invoked to create an instance.
This would also make the property "x" available on every instance of B.

Answer (score 0):

the value of `x` is stored in `b.__proto__.x` and not `b.x` that's why the `hasOwnProperty` method returns false.

Comment: Can you explain without non-standard properties, please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks gp & all:

```
function B () { A.call(this); };
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
var b = new B();
b.hasOwnProperty('x'); // => true
```

The above code is adding 'x' to b.