# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<AbstractAjaxReq> has no method 'getAjaxResponse'

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to implement some good OOP practices into my javascript somehow. As you can see I am having an abstractAjaxRequest and then giving it some children that define its getAjaxResponse function. I get the error posted at the bottom, on this line: `self.getAjaxResponse()`. Anyone see the error of my ways?

```
function soapReq() {
    var ajaxRequest = new SignInAjaxReq();
    ajaxRequest.init();
    var SOAPRequest = getSOAPHead();
    var bodyArgs = getLoginAttempt();
    SOAPRequest += getSOAPBody(bodyArgs[0], bodyArgs[1], bodyArgs[2]);
    SOAPRequest += getSOAPFoot();

    var url = 'xxx'
    ajaxRequest.ajaxRequest.open('POST', url, true);
    ajaxRequest.ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    ajaxRequest.ajaxRequest.send(SOAPRequest);
}    

function AbstractAjaxReq() {
    var self = this;
    this.init = function() {
        self.ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        self.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(self.ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
                self.getAjaxResponse() // error here
            }
        };
        return self.ajaxRequest;
    };
};

function SignInAjaxReq() {
    var self = this;
    this.getAjaxResponse = function() {
        var xml = self.ajaxRequest.responseXML;
        var x=xml.getElementsByTagName("signInResult");
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
            console.log(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
    };
};
SignInAjaxReq.prototype = new AbstractAjaxReq();

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<AbstractAjaxReq> has no method 'getAjaxResponse' SoapRequest.js:42
    self.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: what line does the error come from?

Comment: That is in the question. Thanks.

Comment: `this.ajaxRequest.readyState` the `this` is the function scoped `this`, not the AbstractAjaxReq.`this` - if you know what i mean to say :)

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: to clarify: you are using `this` in multiple levels of fn(){ fn{} } - if I remeber correctly this is a different `this` every time

Comment: @birdspider Thanks! What syntax would I use to correct that?

Comment: @btf217 check out Vache's link - js is not oop based but prototype based which is supposedlty very powerfull but different from classic oop

Comment: Javascript is not c# or java. It is actually a functional language that supports prototypical inheritance (which is not the same as object oriented). So what you are doing is not really 'good OOP practices'. Better to stick to javascript best practices IMHO.

Comment: @MikeCheel Wouldn't that mean a lot of code duplication in this circumstance?

Comment: I didn't say avoid reuse (dry principle). I'm just saying what might be best practices in an OOP world are not necessarily best practices in javascript land. I've seen a lot of problems where people think they can just treat javascript like c# and java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inheritance is flawed. When you [create the prototype by `new AbstractReq()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572), then the `self` closure variable will point to that *prototype object* - which does not have a `getAjaxResponse` method.

Fix #1: Use [correct inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572):

```
function AbstractAjaxReq() {
    var self = this;
    this.init = function() {
        self.ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        self.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(self.ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
                self.getAjaxResponse() // no more error here
            }
        };
        return self.ajaxRequest;
    };
};

function SignInAjaxReq() {
    AbstractAjaxReq.call(this); // invoke the super constructor
    var self = this;
    this.getAjaxResponse = function() {
        var xml = self.ajaxRequest.responseXML;
        var x=xml.getElementsByTagName("signInResult");
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
            console.log(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
    };
};
SignInAjaxReq.prototype = Object.create(AbstractAjaxReq.prototype);
```

Fix #2: Assign the actual instance to `self` by creating the variable in the `init` function:

```
function AbstractAjaxReq() {
    this.init = function() {
        var self = this; // here!
        self.ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        self.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(self.ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
                self.getAjaxResponse() // no more error here
            }
        };
        return self.ajaxRequest;
    };
};
```

---

Also, [use the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572)! Example:

```
var abstractAjaxPrototype = {
    init: function() {
        var self = this; // here!
        this.ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (self.ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
                self.getAjaxResponse() // no more error here
            }
        };
        return this.ajaxRequest;
    }
};
function SignInAjaxReq() { }
SignInAjaxReq.prototype = Object.create(abstractAjaxPrototype);
SignInAjaxReq.prototype.getAjaxResponse = function() {
    var xml = this.ajaxRequest.responseXML;
    var x = xml.getElementsByTagName("signInResult");
    for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
        console.log(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
};
```

And: don't use `init` methods, use the constructor:

```
function AbstractAjaxReq() {
    var self = this; // here!
    self.ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    self.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(self.ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
            self.getAjaxResponse() // no more error here
        }
    };
};
function SignInAjaxReq() {
    AbstractAjaxReq.call(this); // invoke the super constructor
}
SignInAjaxReq.prototype = Object.create(abstractAjaxPrototype);
SignInAjaxReq.prototype.getAjaxResponse = function() {
    var xml = this.ajaxRequest.responseXML;
    var x = xml.getElementsByTagName("signInResult");
    for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
        console.log(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
};

// Usage:
var ajaxRequest = new SignInAjaxReq();
// no ajaxRequest.init()!
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make it notice my childs getAjaxResponse() function?

Comment: I just posted 4 fixes each of which alone would have got it to work :-)