# Add a method to prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

I created a Sprite Class and then derived a Dragon class from the sprite class. I am trying to add in an action method only to the Dragon Class, but it is not working. I'm adding the action method to Dragon.prototype in the same way that I added methods to the Sprite class with Sprite.prototype, but if I create an instance of my Dragon class, I'm not able to call the action method I defined in the Dragon prototype.

If I change Dragon.prototype.action to Sprite.prototype.action, the code works perfectly. For this example, it wouldn't matter, but I want to be able to set up methods for specific classes later on. What am I doing wrong? Should I just settle for more method names? If the answer should be obvious I apologize, and thanks for your help.

```
var Sprite = function(spriteSheet, rows, columns, x, y, width, height){
    this.frameSpeed = 1;
    this.spriteSheet = spriteSheet;
//The starting Location
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
//The width and height of the sprite
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
//Variables for movement
    this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
//rows and columns of our spritesheet
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;
//our variables needed to animate the sprite.
    this.sourceWidth = this.spriteSheet.width/this.columns;
    this.sourceHeight = this.spriteSheet.height/this.rows;
    this.sourceX = 0;
    this.sourceY = 0;
    this.frameCount = this.rows * this.columns;
    this.currentFrame = 0;
}

Sprite.prototype.update = function(){

    this.y+=this.ySpeed;
    this.x+= this.xSpeed;

    if(this.currentFrame >= this.frameCount){
        this.currentFrame = 0;
    }

    this.row = Math.floor( this.currentFrame / this.columns);
    this.column = Math.floor( this.currentFrame % this.columns);

    this.currentFrame+=this.frameSpeed;
    this.sourceX = this.column * this.sourceWidth;
    this.sourceY = this.row * this.sourceHeight;

}

Sprite.prototype.draw = function(){
     context.drawImage( this.spriteSheet, this.sourceX, this.sourceY, this.sourceWidth, this.sourceHeight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

var mySprite = new Sprite(smiley,4,4,100,50,100,100);

var Dragon = function( x, y, width, height){
    var dragon = new Sprite(dragonSheet,4,3,x,y, width,height);
    dragon.frameSpeed = .5;
    dragon.xSpeed = 4;
    return dragon;
} 

Dragon.prototype.action = function(){
    if(this.x>500){
        this.x = -100;
    }
}

var dragon1 = new Dragon(70,170,80,50);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why does Dragon.prototype.action not work when changing it to Sprite.prototype.action works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to your `Sprite` constructor, the `Dragon` function does `return` an object - and is therefore no more a constructor, but a mere factory function. It does create and return a  `Sprite` instace, which will inherit from `Sprite.prototype`, not from `Dragon.prototype`. See [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572) for details.

To fix this, use `Dragon` as a constructor. `this` will be the instance, and to initialise it you'd `.call()` the `Sprite` function on it before giving it dragon-specific properties. The newly created instances would then inherit from `Dragon.prototype`.

To set up the prototype chain correctly, you need to make `Dragon.prototype` inherit from `Sprite.prototype` - so that all created `Dragon` instances will have the `Sprite` methods as well, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572).

```
function Dragon(x, y, width, height) {
    Sprite.call(this, dragonSheet, 4, 3, x, y, width, height);
    this.frameSpeed = .5;
    this.xSpeed = 4;
}
Dragon.prototype = Object.create(Sprite.prototype);
Dragon.prototype.constructor = Dragon;

Dragon.prototype.action = …;

var dragon1 = new Dragon(70,170,80,50);
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me a quick example of what using Dragon as the constructor would look like?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `Dragon.prototype.action` is not called when you do something like:

```
var d = new Dragon(...);
d.action(); // won't work
```

is because you are choosing to return a newly-created `Sprite` object from the `Dragon` constructor, instead of using `this`, which will have been set up as a new `Dragon` instance for you upon having been called with `new`. Because you are explicitly invoking the `Sprint` constructor with new, and then returning that object, the object has been set up with Sprite's prototype (and doesn't know anything about Dragon).

There are several ways to do inheritance in JavaScript, but I think in your case you could get away with just changing your `Dragon` constructor to call `Sprite` with this specified explicitly, instead having it act on your new Dragon object:

```
var Dragon = function( x, y, width, height){
    Sprite.call(this, dragonSheet,4,3,x,y, width,height); // act on `this`
    this.frameSpeed = .5;
    this.xSpeed = 4;
    // 'return this' is implied for constructors
}
```