# javascript: object inheritance is not able understand

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am working inheritance in JavaScript, here, have created two objects. on the below code, when try to alert as `alert(newOnj.whatAreYou());`, now, it is working fine. But, when i try to alert `alert(newOnj.whatAreYounow());`, now, am getting error as `'newOnj.whatAreYounow is not a function'`. Actually, have inherited parent class to child class as `subGadget.prototype = new Gadget();`. what is the thing that i `haven't` understood here? please

```
function Gadget() { 
   this.name = "Alex"; 
   this.color = "red"; 
   this.whatAreYou = function(){ 
     return 'I am a ' + this.color + ' ' + this.name; 
   }
}
  function subGadget() { 
     this.whatAreYounow = function(){ 
     return 'Now, I am a ' + this.color + ' ' + this.name; 
   }
}

  subGadget.prototype = new Gadget();

  var newOnj = new Gadget();

 alert(newOnj.whatAreYounow());
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write -

```
var newOnj = new subGadget();
```

Comment: … and he would need to [inherit correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572) from `Gadget`.