# Correct Javascript prototype pattern definition/example

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, prototype

I'm reading up on my Javascript and came across two very different Prototype pattern examples through my readings. Here is the example from [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781118026694.do):

> Each function is created with a prototype `property`, which is an
>   object containing properties and methods that should be available to
>   instances of a particular reference type. This object is literally a
>   prototype for the object to be created once the constructor is called.

```
function Person(){}

Person.prototype.name = "Nicholas";
Person.prototype.age = 29;
Person.prototype.job = "Dev";
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
  alert(this.name);
};

var person1 = new Person();
person1.sayName(); // "Nicholas"

var person2= new Person();
person2.sayName(); // "Nicholas"

alert(person1.sayName == person2.sayName); // true
```

And here is the example from [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025832.do)

> The GoF refer to the prototype pattern as one which creates objects
>   based on a template of an existing object through cloning.
>
> We can think of the prototype pattern as being based on prototypal
>   inheritance where we create objects which act as prototypes for other
>   objects. The prototype object itself is effectively used as a
>   blueprint for each object the constructor creates. If the prototype of
>   the constructor function used contains a property called name for
>   example (as per the code sample lower down), then each object created
>   by that same constructor will also have this same property.
>
> Reviewing the definitions for this pattern in existing
>   (non-JavaScript) literature, we may find references to classes once
>   again. The reality is that prototypal inheritance avoids using classes
>   altogether. There isn't a "definition" object nor a core object in
>   theory. We're simply creating copies of existing functional objects.
>
> One of the benefits of using the prototype pattern is that we're
>   working with the prototypal strengths JavaScript has to offer natively
>   rather than attempting to imitate features of other languages. With
>   other design patterns, this isn't always the case.
>
> Not only is the pattern an easy way to implement inheritance, but it
>   can also come with a performance boost as well: when defining a
>   function in an object, they're all created by reference (so all child
>   objects point to the same function) instead of creating their own
>   individual copies.
>
> For those interested, real prototypal inheritance, as defined in the
>   ECMAScript 5 standard, requires the use of Object.create (which we
>   previously looked at earlier in this section). To remind ourselves,
>   Object.create creates an object which has a specified prototype and
>   optionally contains specified properties as well (e.g Object.create(
>   prototype, optionalDescriptorObjects )).

```
var myCar = {

  name: "Ford Escort",

  drive: function () {
    console.log( "Weeee. I'm driving!" );
  },

  panic: function () {
    console.log( "Wait. How do you stop this thing?" );
  }

};

// Use Object.create to instantiate a new car
var yourCar = Object.create( myCar );

// Now we can see that one is a prototype of the other
console.log( yourCar.name );
```

What exactly am I missing here? Is the 2nd one an updated version of the first one? Is it a different pattern entirely? Why isn't he using the `.prototype` in the 2nd example?

Comment: you should use the 2nd one.

Comment: you can use whichever, just pick the one you feel most comfortable with. I suggest you reading *Javascript - the good parts*

Comment: So you're saying they both do the exact same thing but the 2nd one does it better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct javascript inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572)

Comment: The question about inheritance revolves around using the object.create and the new keyword, this question revolves more around the prototype keyword and it's concepts.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of research it turns out that both of them are prototype patterns, even tough they look completely different and many might think that only the 1st one is right.

Yes the 2nd version is the updated one and most likely to be used.

No it's not a different pattern it's the exact prototype pattern.

The reason why it's not using `.prototype` is because of `Object.create` and how it's first argument can be an object from which it uses the prototype.

Hope this clears things up for everyone :)