# Javascript inheritance with eventListener

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a class `designMain` which extends `design`.

I have found that if I set an eventListener in `design`, when the event is fired, all references to `this` will only refer to the non extended `design` object. Is there a way to overcome this shortcoming of my extended class?

**UPDATE** - I've included an ES6 version which works as expected and shows what I am trying to accomplish - namely that `this` with extended classes will always refer to the extended class even with code (e.g. addEventListener) within the base class. In this case `this.name` should always be from the extended class.

Here is [a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/bec2gt4e/)

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    Design (click will fail)
</div>

<div id="test2">
    DesignMain (click will succeed)
</div>
```

javascript

```
design = (function() {
  function design() {
    this.name = "design";

    var _this = this;
    var e = document.getElementById("test");
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      _this.callHello();
    });
  }

  design.prototype.callHello = function() {
    // I expect that this.name will be "designMain"
    console.log(this.name)
    // will fail if called from the design class eventListener
    this.hello();
  }

  return design;
})();


designMain = (function() {
  function designMain() {
    this.name = "designMain";
    this.init();
  }

  designMain.prototype.init = function() {
    this.extend();
    var _this = this;
    var e = document.getElementById("test2");
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      _this.callHello();
    });
  }

  designMain.prototype.extend = function() {
    var old = new design();
    // save reference to original methods
    this._designMain = Object.create(old);
    for (var name in this._designMain) {
      if (!this[name]) {
        this[name] = this._designMain[name]
      }
    }
  }

  designMain.prototype.hello = function() {
    alert("Hello " + this.name);
  }

  return designMain;
})();


var t = new designMain();
```

Using ES6 - it works as expected ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/nfsfrhge/))

```
class design {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "design";

    var _this = this;
    var e = document.getElementById("test");
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      _this.callHello();
    });
  };

  callHello() {
    // should be "designMain"
    console.log(this.name)
    this.hello();
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  };
  set name(name) {
    this._name = name;
  };
}


class designMain extends design {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "designMain";
    var _this = this;
    var e = document.getElementById("test2");
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      _this.callHello();
    });
  };

  hello() {
    alert("Hello " + this.name);
  }

}

t = new designMain();
```

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want `design` to inherit from `designMain`? If yes, why didn't you do anything to achieve that? And what is this `extend` method supposed to do?

Comment: Your `ceate` method (which should be static, btw) is deprecated. Just use `Object.create` instead.

Comment: @Bergi - I've updated the question with an ES6 version which behaves as expected - namely that designMain inherits extends design and all references to `this` will be designMain methods and properties. I updated my code to use Object.create, and fiddled around with static functions, but was not able to get `this` to update within code generated with the base "class". Is it possible to simulate true class inheritance without using the ES6 Class way?

Comment: [Sure it's possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10898859/1048572). The problem with your original code is that it somehow conflates composition (designMain contains a design) with inheritance (design uses designMain methods)

Comment: @Bergi - Great link, thanks. It gave me what I needed and I've posted an anwser for anyone who follows. If you want to post an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bergi and the link he posted - I have a solution. Extending / inheriting was way simpler using `Object.create` and I only needed to add `design.call(this)` to run the constructor of the base class.

```
designMain = (function() {
  designMain.prototype = Object.create(design.prototype);

  function designMain() {
    design.call(this)
```

Working solution:

```
design = (function() {
  function design() {
    this.name = "design";

    var _this = this;
    var e = document.getElementById("test");
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      _this.callHello();
    });
  }

  design.prototype.callHello = function() {
    // will fail if called from the design class eventListener
    console.log(this.name)
    this.hello();
  }

  return design;
})();


designMain = (function() {
  designMain.prototype = Object.create(design.prototype);

  function designMain() {
    design.call(this)
    this.name = "designMain";
    this.init();
  }

  designMain.prototype.init = function() {
    var _this = this;
    var e = document.getElementById("test2");
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      _this.callHello();
    });
  }

  designMain.prototype.hello = function() {
    alert("Hello " + this.name);
  }

  return designMain;
})();


var t = new designMain();
```