# Javascript Prototype object and Inheritance

Tags: javascript

what is different between Object.create(functionname.prototype) vs new Student() constructor call.

```
    function Student(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
     function UniversityStudent(id){
        this.id= id;
    }


    // 1st way
    UniversityStudent.prototype = Object.create(Student.prototype);
    var std = new UniversityStudent(123);
    // but I cannot access std.name why ?

    // 2nd way
    UniversityStudent.prototype = new Student("Lasith Malinga");
   var std1 = new UniversityStudent(123);
   // When I use std1.name now then it can
```

When I use 1st way then I cannot access Student`s object properties, but I use 2nd way it can, What is difference. I think both way are same... Is it wrong ?

Comment: Well, have you inspected the objects you created in the console? What `name` do you think will they have?

Comment: Your edit significantly altered the question, for this situation have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance/). However, my point remains: where would `std` even get a `.name` from?

Comment: use any browser console and try std.name :D

Comment: I don't need a browser console to see that it's undefined. I'm asking what value you did expect it to have, so that I can clear up your confusion.

Comment: Pls what are u asking... I did not understand ?

Comment: You are asking why you cannot access `std.name`. I ask what you expected to get when you accessed it.

Comment: I dont need any clarification coz I got nice url https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create